# in_array does not work correctly when dealing with strings

Tags: php

This code:

```
var_dump(in_array("000", array(",00", ".00")));
var_dump(in_array("111", array(",11", ".11")));
```

output:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

Why does the first line return `true` ?

Comment: Could it have anything to do with [this behaviour](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php#91911)?

Comment: I've edited your title. Please remember that "does not work" is a vague description of a problem for other people searching for the same problem!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It has to do with PHP's type coercion. The "000" essentially gets converted to just `0`. To force it to use strict type checking, `in_array()` accepts a third parameter.

```
var_dump(in_array("000", array(",00", ".00"), true));
```

output:

```
bool(false)
```

EDIT: @andrekeller also pointed out the `".00"` probably gets converted to int `0` as well. Moral of the story, don't trust PHP to get types right.

Comment: I would have written something similar, +1

Comment: agreed, deleted my similar answer

Comment: @andrekeller was going to upvote you too. You're answer is also correct as it mentions the .00 being converted as well. Knowing PHP its probably both

Comment: @Cfreak: well then update your answer, does not make sense have to almost identical answers