# In a Twig template {{0 in ['a', 'b', '99']}} returns 1. WHY?

Tags: php, twig

Question heading already asks it:

In a Twig template `{{0 in ['a', 'b', '99']}}` prints `1`. WHY? I have `'0'` as a value and I can't check it against arrays, as that value always pops up as existing. And at the end of the day: How do I achieve the goal of checking zero against the array of strings, in Twig?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28437510/3933332

Comment: @Rizier123 thanks, but that Q&A doesn't provide me with a solution on how to achieve my goal in Twig. I got the reasons for this, but also need a solution.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's type coercion for comparisons goes to integers when necessary. You're checking if an integer is in the array. `(int) 'a'` is coerced to `0` for this comparison.  So `0` is seen as being in the array.

To avoid this, you can use `in_array` with the strict option:

```
in_array('0', ['a', 'b', '99'], true)
```

Comment: With this in mind, I believe ```var_dump(in_array(0, ['1','2']))``` should yield ```true```, correct? It yields ```false``` though (in PHP 7 at least). Same goes for ```var_dump(in_array(0, [1,2]))``` So why?

Comment: Because the string `'1'` is coerced to `1`.  Character strings are coerced to `0` when compared with any integer.

Comment: Ok, so how do we compare against integer zero then, in Twig of course?

Comment: For an array of integers (or integer string), use `in`.  For an array with a mix of integers and character strings, my answer is above: `in_array` with the strict option.

Comment: Twig has ```in_array``` function?

Comment: Not directly, you'll have to create an extension or use an existing one.